# Fechas y exportar tabla

Tags: base-de-datos, r, date

El primer problema:

Tengo un fichero de datos de entrada que contiene fechas en formato `ddmmyy`, sobre las que debo operar, y al importarlo en R lo reconoce como factor. Lo que he hecho es convertirlo en caracter usando `as.character` y entonces lo he transformado a fecha usando `as.date`, por ejemplo

```
df1$fcontrol<-as.Date(df1$fcontrol, format="%d%m%Y") 
df2$fparto<-as.Date(df2$fparto, format="%d%m%Y") 

df1$Var1<-as.numeric(df1$fcontrol - df2$fparto)
```

En todos los casos, el nuevo formato de fecha en mis ficheros de trabajo y de salida ya no es `"ddmmyy"` sino `"yymmdd"` y no sé porqué pasa, si claramente en la orden format le estoy especificando `ddmmyy`. Qué debo hacer?

El segundo problema

Este es el formato de salida que quiero que tengan mis datos:

```
ES06000011030003012012210220121360 4.07 4.38  678
ES06000011030003012012200320121460 3.46 4.81   20
ES0600001103000301201219042012 980 3.69 5.46   54
ES0600001103000301201212072012 660             32
```

Donde las 14 primeras posiciones representan un ID, las 8 siguientes son una fecha, las 8 siguientes otra fecha, las 4 siguientes parámetro1 de interés, las 5 siguientes parametro2 con una separación decimal, las 5 siguientes parametro3 con una separación decimal y las 5 siguientes parametro4.

En R lo que consigo usando

```
write.table(Datos, "Datos_TD_LCR.DAT", row.names = FALSE, col.names=FALSE, quote = FALSE, sep="")
```

es algo del tipo

```
ES060000110300030120122102201213604.074.38678
ES060000110300030120122003201214603.464.8120
ES06000011030003012012190420129803.695.4654
ES0600001103000301201212072012660NANA32
```

Y no sé de qué manera conseguir lo que necesito.

Answer (score 1):

#### Primer problema

Tienes una confusión, un dato `Date` no tiene formato, justamente por que es una fecha, la representación del dato y el dato en si mismo son dos cosas distintas, cuando haces algo como esto:

```
> as.Date('12072018', format='%d%m%Y')
[1] "2018-07-12"
```

No estas diciendo que quieres que la fecha tenga un determinado formato, sino que la cadena de entrada para convertir lo tiene. Cualquier `Date` en R se mostrará como en el ejemplo anterior, con el formato ISO es decir `yyyy-mm-dd`, es el mejor formato para mostrar este dato ya que no es ambiguo. Mostrar la fecha como `07-12-2018` tendrá distintas interpretaciones según dónde vivas. Pero recuerda, una fecha sigue siendo una fecha a pesar de la forma en que se muestra. Si eventualmente necesitarás representar una fecha de determinada manera, deberás hacerlo como una cadena, por ejemplo:

```
d <- as.Date('12072018', format='%d%m%Y')
format(d, "%d/%m/%Y")
[1] "12/07/2018"
```

#### Segundo problema

Por lo que entiendo del formato de archivo que esperas conseguir es de columnas de longitudes fijas. No es tan simple, en R no hay una rutina que grabe este tipo de archivos, pero lo más sencillo es incorporar el paquete `gdata` (obviamente hay que instalarlo antes). por ejemplo, supongamos que tenemos el siguiente `data.frame`:

```
df <- data.frame(NOMBRE=c('JUAN','JUAN', 'PEDRO', 'PEDRO', 'PEDRO', 'LUIS', 'LUIS'),
                 MONEDA=c('EUR', 'USD', 'EUR', 'CLP', 'USD', 'GBP', 'EUR'),
                 MONTO=c(10.1, 20.5, 30, 10, 20, 30, 10))

df

  NOMBRE MONEDA MONTO
1   JUAN    EUR  10.1
2   JUAN    USD  20.5
3  PEDRO    EUR  30.0
4  PEDRO    CLP  10.0
5  PEDRO    USD  20.0
6   LUIS    GBP  30.0
7   LUIS    EUR  10.0
```

Y queremos generar un archivo con un formato específico, por ejemplo, 5 caracteres para `NOMBRE`, 3 para `MONEDA` y 5 para `MONTO`, podríamos hacerlo así:

```
library(gdata)
write.fwf(df, file = "salida.txt", colnames = FALSE, width = c(5,3,5), sep="")
```

Si verificamos el archivo de salida:

```
JUAN EUR 10.1
JUAN USD 20.5
PEDROEUR 30.0
PEDROCLP 10.0
PEDROUSD 20.0
LUIS GBP 30.0
LUIS EUR 10.0
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu explicación, he resuelto todo lo que necesitaba.